# Updating Dictionary of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm essentially reading in a CSV File and am creating an Object called "City" which is created using attributes passed to the constructor "city_constructor". **Edit: The file has "City" information on every line**. I have a dict of dicts which I am struggling to update, which takes in key values associated with 2 different Classes:

```
% d is an iterator obtained from dictReader = csv.DictReader(placesFile)
% Defining my dict of dicts called places
places = {"City":{}, "Country":{}}
```

And I then try and add the new object into my dict of dicts as follows, but this does not appear to be working. Is there a way to do this?:

```
for d in dictReader:
    new_City = city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"])
    places.update({"City":new_City})
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `places['City'] = new_City`?

Comment: Giving a sample of 2 different ``new_City`` contents, and the expected final content of ``places`` would probably help you understand your own problem, and help us help you. There are several element that are left for interpretation and I strongly suspect that even the title of the question is mis-guiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to update your `places` dictionary with:

```
places["City"] = new_City
```

If your file has "City" information on every line, then I am guessing you would be doing `new_City = city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"])` on every line. In that case, your `places` should be like:

```
places = {"City":[], "Country":[]}
```

And you would update it as:

```
for d in dictReader:
    new_City = city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"])
    places["City"].append(new_City)
```

If it has to be a dict of dicts, then your `places` should be structured something like:

```
{
    "City": {
        "City_1": <city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"]) of first line>,
        "City_2": <city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"]) of second line>,
        "City_3": <city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"]) of third line>,
    }
}
```

That is, there has to be a new key associated with every line a new city is encountered. May be something like this:

```
count = 0
for d in dictReader:
    new_City = city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"])
    _a_dict = {'City_{}'.format(count):new_City}
    count += 1
    places["City"].update(_a_dict)
```

Comment: Thank You. However, I still need "places" to be a dict of dicts, as isn't this a dict of lists?

Comment: What do you expect the key to be, for every new city on every line? There will be a list involved in the `places` variable since there are multiple occurrences of cities (one for every line of the file)

Comment: Thank you very much. May I just ask what the purpose of "count" is?

Comment: To generate the new key. It is used in `'City_{}'.format(count)`. It is what generates new keys: City_1, City_2, etc

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question. What if I already have a key in mind (rather than generating new keys), which is a Header in the CSV File called "Continent"?

Comment: @user131983 It would be: `_a_dict = {d['continent']:new_City}`

Comment: Thanks again. Also, would you know how I would refer to the value `Population` in `places` for the key `City`? I tried doing the following                                                             `for x in places:

    if x['City'] or x['Country'] == "Population":
            population += 1`

Answer (score 1):

For updating a single key, you should use this instead:

```
places["City"] = new_City
```

Comment: Thanks. However, my file has "City" information on every line as the user Shaktimaan stated.

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in dictReader:
    new_City = city_constructor(d["Population"],d["Area"])
    try:
        places["City"].append(new_City)
    except KeyError:
        places["City"] = [new_City]
```

at least I think ... assuming I understand what you are asking for