# Accessing elements in dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am parsing some information from a CSV File and am inputting it into a dict of dicts. The inner dict `v` contains the following elements `{'140725AD4': <mod.City object at 1x3259C2D1>, '631315AD2': <mod.City object at 0x023A4870>}`. How would I access the object `<mod.city object at 0x0138C3B0>` for example?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this question is the follow up for this one - [Updating Dictionary of Dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924443/updating-dictionary-of-dictionaries-in-python) you would have to do this:

```
inner_dict = places["City"]
for _, city_obj in inner_dict.items():
    print city_obj.population # Assuming population is one of the member variables of the class mod.city
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a structure like the following:

```
john = {
    "name": "John",
    "family": {
        "son": "Ret",
        "daughter": "Pat"
    }
}
```

You can access the John son's name like this:

```
john['family']['son']
```

This will return "Ret"

In your case, if City object is a DICT you can use:

```
dict['140725AD4']['population']
```

If your City object is just a Class you can do

```
dict['140725AD4'].getPopulation()
```

or

```
dict['140725AD4'].population
```

**How it works?**
A dictionary is a hashmap of pairs (name, value). Whenever you call a name the value is given. In Python, the value can be anything, from int to a Class.

So when in a dict you ask for a name inside a dict like dict['name'] you get back the value associated with it. In this case its your City object. Then you can call anything related to the value: functions, variables...